# How to Support multiple screen for android layout design

Tags: android

I am using android2.2.I have created drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi,res/drawable-xhdpi.
I  created layout folder for large,medium,small screen size.I used  in the manifest file.Still i am unable to get support for multiple screen size.For example image size and layout margin remain same for large,medium,small screen size.Can anyone help me?

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: i also tested it by using only one layout folder

Comment: no you should use multiple layout files, layout-xlarge-land,layout-xlarge,layout-land,layout-port like this

Comment: I am also working on this, i get success by doing like this

Comment: Which measures are ok for an android developer if the designer will make the design and send us only pictures? I mean it should be 420x700 or what? I just cant understand that designers make the design about which measures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

name layout folders with layout-small,layout-normal,layout-large,layout-xlarge.It works according to mobile dpi.It doesnot depend on screen size.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to create layout for all screen, u can use **weightsum** for manage them.

this sample code may help u.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:weightSum="1.0">



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```